# Организация видео хостинга для приложения

Tags: сервер, передача-данных, организация

У меня есть приложение для мобильных. Весит оно 13mb, но подгружает дополнительно, по необходимости, 1.2GB видео контента. Один пользователь в минуту загружает примерно 30mb видео контента, и так продолжается, пока не закончиться игровая сессия.
Расчитываю, что у приложения будет много скачиваний. Хочу взять собственный сервер, т.к. крупные организации берут много за передачу данных. Какой мощности сервер мне брать, как огрганизовать данные на сервере, чтобы к 1.2GB данных подключались много пользователей одновременно и как, по необходимости, подключить дополнительный интернет, если скорости мне не хватит? И сколько примерно будет стоить в таком случае 1GB передачи данных?

Comment: Стоп... С чего Вы взяли, что провайдеры берут плату за трафик? Я такого нигде не слышал. Хотя, возможно, на так называемых хостингах это и присутствует, но... у меня на VPS по-моему, такого нет.

Comment: Некоторые провайдеры/хостеры так делают. У меня был такой, 1тб в месяц и все. А в случае автора вопроса, это 30 клиентов в день.